# gdb 7 segfaulting

Tags: macos, gdb, g++, segmentation-fault

I installed gdb 7.2 via macports on osx 10.6. However when I run it, I get

`unable to read unknown load command 0x1a 

Segmentation fault`

I also tried compiling it manually but I still get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Thanks,
--Sid

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
sudo chgrp procmod /opt/local/bin/fsf-gdb

sudo chmod g+s /opt/local/bin/fsf-gdb
```

Of course change `"/opt/local/bin/"` to reflect your path to gbd and change `"fsf-gdb"` to the name of the compiled gdb. I assumed `"standard"` path and name given by macports.

Answer (score 0):

GDB is not actively maintained on Mac OS. Your best bet is to open a bug in GDB [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/).